# Prove that $F$ is constant on $S$.

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $F'(x;y)=0$ for every $x$ in an open convex set $S$ and for every $y$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$, prove that $F$ is a constant on $S$, where $S\subset\mathbb{R^n}$.

Somewhere I need to define a function like $g(t)=F(x+ty)$ which would connect two points in $S$ and then I could use the mean value theorem on $g(t)$.

I am unable to create such a function.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What you mean by $F'(x;y)$? Is this the directional derivative?

Comment: yes....@copper.hat

Answer (score 2):

Your notation seems somehow weird to me, anyway if $F'(x;y)=D_yf(x)=0$ (or what do you mean by that?), then all partial derrivatives vanish and hence are continuous, so F is differentiable in $S$ with $DF \equiv 0$. Let $x,x'\in S$ and consider $g:[0,1]\to S , t\mapsto F((1-t)x+tx')$. Since $g'(t)=DF((1-t)x+tx')(-x+x')^t=0$ g is constant, hence $F(x)=g(0)=g(1)=F(x')$, the claim follows.

Answer (score 2):

Pick $x_0,x_1 \in S$. Let $\gamma(t) = x_0+t (x_1-x_0)$, for $t \in [0,1]$. Let $g = F \circ \gamma$. Then $g'(t) = F'(\gamma(t), x_1-x_0)  = 0$, hence $g$ is constant and so $F(x_0) = F(x_1)$. Since $x_0,x_1$ were arbitrary, we are finished.